# Deliverymethod fax in docusign create and send API - demo environment

Tags: docusignapi

Hi Trying to use the DocuSign createsendEnvelope API for a recipient with delivery method FAX and fax number. However in the demo environment the API needs a recipients email and always send out the email. The document is not faxed to the number provided. Can any one confirm if the demo environment is disabled for faxing options?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1):

The release notes for the "Fax Out" feature in the DocuSign SOAP API describe how to send via fax with the SOAP API (http://www.docusign.com/sites/default/files/DocuSignReleaseNotes-Jun-1-2012-Final.pdf).  I tried to apply the same rational to send an envelope via fax with the REST API -- here's my "Create Envelope" request:

```
POST https://{{env}}.docusign.net/restapi/{{version}}/accounts/{{acctId}}/envelopes

{
  "emailSubject": "Please sign this",
  "emailBlurb": "Please sign...thanks!",
  "status": "sent",
  "enableWetSign": "true",
  "recipients": {
      "signers": [
        {
            "name": "John Doe",
            "email": "johnsemail@outlook.com",
            "faxNumber": "2069347947",
            "recipientId": "1",
            "routingOrder": "1",
            "deliveryMethod": "Fax",
        }]
   },
   "documents": [
        {
            "name": "TestFile.pdf",
            "documentId": "1",
            "fileExtension": "pdf",
            "documentBase64" : "DOCUMENT_BYTES"
        }
    ]
}
```

Unfortunately, I receive the following error in response to the request (even though the fax number I specified is a valid fax number):

```
{
    "errorCode": "INVALID_FAXNUMBER",
    "message": "Fax Number is invalid."
}
```

To troubleshoot further, I tried a little reverse-engineering in an attempt to determine what properties DocuSign expects you to set for a Fax recipient.

First, using the DocuSign web console, I created/sent a new Envelope with a single recipient where the delivery method = fax.  Here's a screenshot of the Status pane from the DocuSign web console for this envlope (immediately after I sent it): 
[image: status pane]

Next, I used the REST API to execute a "Get Recipients" request (`GET https://{{env}}.docusign.net/restapi/{{version}}/accounts/{{acctId}}/envelopes/{{envId}}/recipients`) -- with the goal of examining the recipient object in the response to determine which properties need to be set for a Fax recipient.  Here's the response I received:

```
{
    "signers": [
        {
            "signInEachLocation": "false",
            "name": "John Doe",
            "email": "johnsemail@outlook.com",
            "recipientId": "1",
            "recipientIdGuid": "977e571d-6613-492c-8a75-9c207d46c03c",
            "requireIdLookup": "false",
            "userId": "03c8a856-c0ae-41bf-943d-ac6e92db66a8",
            "routingOrder": "1",
            "status": "sent"
        }
    ],
    "agents": [],
    "editors": [],
    "intermediaries": [],
    "carbonCopies": [],
    "certifiedDeliveries": [],
    "inPersonSigners": [],
    "recipientCount": "1",
    "currentRoutingOrder": "1"
}
```

Interestingly, the API response contains no mention of "deliveryMethod", and no mention of the fax number that was specified for the recipient.  This would lead me to believe that perhaps the "fax" delivery method isn't fully supported via the REST API at this time.  (If it is supported, then perhaps someone with DocuSign can chime in here and explain how to send via fax (with the API).)

In the meantime, if using the DocuSign SOAP API is an option for you, you might try that route, as it appears that the "Fax Out" feature was initially designed for and implemented in the SOAP API (so I'd expect it to work there, although I haven't personally tested it).

Comment: Great complete answer Kim that's pretty informative.  I had tested this a while back and I don't believe fax is enabled in the REST api.  As you state, it IS available through DocuSign's SOAP api though...