# how to correct a docusign recipient to use fax delivery

Tags: docusignapi

I have a docusign envelope created from a template via the REST API.  I have later added either a carbon copy or certified delivery recipient, also via the REST API.  I now want to change that new recipient to have fax delivery.

From my testing (and confirmed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21335449/deliverymethod-fax-in-docusign-create-and-send-api-demo-environment)), it appears that fax is not available via REST, so I'm giving it a try via SOAP, where it appears to be fully documented under the CorrectAndResendEnvelope method.  Sadly, my experience is that the method call succeeds but there is no indication that it actually works.

Here is what I see being sent in my SOAP call:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tns="http://www.docusign.net/API/3.0" xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <env:Body>
    <tns:CorrectAndResendEnvelope>
      <tns:Correction>
        <tns:EnvelopeID>6bf7d156-a2fd-4031-aaa5-59fd0f0b6dad</tns:EnvelopeID>
        <tns:RecipientCorrections>
          <tns:RecipientCorrection>
            <tns:PreviousUserName>Joe3 Dealer</tns:PreviousUserName>
            <tns:PreviousEmail>joe3@dealer.com</tns:PreviousEmail>
            <tns:PreviousRoutingOrder>3</tns:PreviousRoutingOrder>
            <tns:CorrectedDeliveryMethod>Fax</tns:CorrectedDeliveryMethod>
            <tns:CorrectedFaxNumber>444-222-3333</tns:CorrectedFaxNumber>
          </tns:RecipientCorrection>
        </tns:RecipientCorrections>
      </tns:Correction>
    </tns:CorrectAndResendEnvelope>
  </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

The call has no errors returned, and this is the result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
  <soap:Header>
    <wsa:Action>http://www.docusign.net/API/3.0/CorrectAndResendEnvelopeResponse</wsa:Action>
    <wsa:MessageID>urn:uuid:86765023-12b3-4485-8c6b-9f3082bffa9a</wsa:MessageID>
    <wsa:RelatesTo>urn:uuid:5b34a777-e33e-420b-8b54-3fcc9abc2742</wsa:RelatesTo>
    <wsa:To>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</wsa:To>
    <wsse:Security>
      <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="Timestamp-14f4572c-9333-43be-b3f5-188d0197a12c">
        <wsu:Created>2015-07-15T20:06:41Z</wsu:Created>
        <wsu:Expires>2015-07-15T20:11:41Z</wsu:Expires>
      </wsu:Timestamp>
    </wsse:Security>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <CorrectAndResendEnvelopeResponse xmlns="http://www.docusign.net/API/3.0">
      <CorrectAndResendEnvelopeResult>
        <RecipientCorrectionStatuses>
          <RecipientCorrectionStatus>
            <CorrectionSucceeded>true</CorrectionSucceeded>
            <RecipientCorrection>
              <PreviousUserName>Joe3 Dealer</PreviousUserName>
              <PreviousEmail>joe3@dealer.com</PreviousEmail>
              <PreviousRoutingOrder>3</PreviousRoutingOrder>
            </RecipientCorrection>
            <RecipientStatus>
              <Type>CertifiedDelivery</Type>
              <Email>joe3@dealer.com</Email>
              <UserName>Joe3 Dealer</UserName>
              <RoutingOrder>3</RoutingOrder>
              <DeclineReason xsi:nil="true"/>
              <Status>Created</Status>
              <RecipientIPAddress/>
            </RecipientStatus>
          </RecipientCorrectionStatus>
        </RecipientCorrectionStatuses>
      </CorrectAndResendEnvelopeResult>
    </CorrectAndResendEnvelopeResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Note that neither the RecipientCorrection nor the RecipientStatus has any mention of delivery method or fax number.  In other tests, if I try changing a different property like the routing order, that change will show in that section.  Also, there is only one recipient on the envelope at RoutingOrder=3, and I see the same thing if I try a CC recipient.  I have the 'Fax Delivery' feature checked in the admin console.

What am I missing?  Thanks for your help.